# Drobo questions

Tags: storage, drobo

If I have 4 drives with data on them, can I just stick them in a drobo and let drobo do the work of striping the drives? Or do I need to copy the data off first?

Comment: Did you read the manual? That info shouldn't be too deeply hidden.

Answer (score 11):

Installing a drive in a Drobo automatically erases that drive. So any data you have on a drive will be lost when you place that drive in a Drobo.